# single quotes in data are shown as &#39;

Tags: reactjs

I am building a new app for the same backend (CouchDB).

The old app works with vanilla javascript and underscore. The new one with PouchDB, React and JSX.

Everywhere single quotes `'` are contained in the data, they arrive at the client as `&#39;`. I checked and to my surprise that is the same in the old app.

What is new is that when inserting the data into html, they are now also shown as `&#39;`. So I suspect this must be caused by React / JSX.

How can this be prevented?

I can't prevent single quotes from existing in the data and they need to be presented as single quotes.

I have tried converting string data before passing it to JSX:

```
if (typeof value === 'string') {
  value = value.replace('&#39;', '\'')
}
```

This works. But it is a horrible hack and it needs to be repeated for every data field in the entire app.